# For Loop Python - Taking cell above

Tags: python, for-loop, jupyter-notebook

I'm not an expert in Python, I'm trying to change all my files to Python code but I don't know how to create a for loop that takes the value of column DC inventory from line above and adds Shipm to DC and US forecast from the same line.

Can you help me?

Thanks!

[excel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYe9S.png)

I tried different options but no success...

Comment: Assuming it's already working fine, do you really NEED to change it to python code? Since you say you're no expert, if you need to make any changes in the future you should stick with what you know, meanwhile learn more python with easier side projects

Comment: you need to show us your python code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

basically, to try this in python you would usually create a dataframe in pandas

import pandas as pd

now you can read your table to python with:

table = pd.read_csv(r"C:\yourfile")

now you can manipulate the table - to read from one line and then from a different line, even in a for-loop - you can use pandas loc method

see here:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html

here is a simple example:

```
### Sample Data Frame - change this to your imported file
data = {'a': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'b': [5, 6, 7, 8],
    'c': [9, 10, 11, 12],
    'd': [13, 14, 15, 16]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
### Initialize a variable to store the result
result = []
### Iterate through the rows of the DataFrame
for i in range(len(df)):
    if i == 0:
        ### If it's the first row, there's no row above, so set NaN
        result.append(None)
    else:
        ### Multiply the value in column 'c' 
        ### of the current row by the value
        ### in column 'd' of the row above
        multiplication_result = df.loc[i, 'c'] * df.loc[i - 1, 'd']
    result.append(multiplication_result)
    ### Add the result as a new column in the DataFrame
    df['result'] = result

### Display the modified DataFrame
print(df)
```

and you get:

```
   a  b   c   d  result
0  1  5   9  13     NaN
1  2  6  10  14   130.0
2  3  7  11  15   154.0
3  4  8  12  16   180.0
```

Comment: thanks so much @lohmar-ashar, I'm trying to learn with resources from here and there, and sometimes it's difficult, but your answer is so clear!! I owe you a beer!

Comment: Thanks, but you got it wrong, the credits should go to @OrielB, I've only edited the formatting of his answer, also if his answer helped you make sure to mark it as such (click on the UP arrow) this way he'll get his points